# Motion of binary planetary system perceptible?

Tags: planets

If one were standing on a body that is part of a binary system such as Pluto/Charon, would the g-forces of the motion of the planet be perceptible by a human?

Comment: What do you mean by perceptible? Astronomically observable? Measurable on a lab experiment? Perceptible g-forces on humans?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Then zhermes' answer applies. Humans feel g-forces of order 1 g (unless they change suddenly). Assuming the planet has Earth-like surface gravity, that puts the planet pretty near the Roche limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean, 'could a person feel it?' - then no.  To be able to feel the effect of the motion, the system would have to be near break-up (with the surface near the [Roche/Tidal limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit)), which never really happens for binary-planets.

For a planet very near a star, it could be perceptible... but in most cases you'd be burned up (etc) due to the close proximity to the star.